FlameRobin unable to connect to Firebird4.0
I have FlameRobin 0.9.3 installed on a Windows machine. I can successfully connect to Firebird 3.0 database running on CentOS
Now I have another Firebird 4.0 database on a separate Almalinux machine and I am not able to connect to it or create a new DB from my FlameRobin. The error I get is

Install incomplete. To complete security database initialization CREATE USER.

I was able to create a test DB from Almalinux itself with
CREATE DATABASE '/db/xeroxnew.fdb' USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey';

But I'm still unable to connect to it from FlameRobin
All necessary libraries for from Firebird 4.0 were installed on Flamerobin machine.
Any ideas?

Does this answer your question? Firebird database SYSDBA connection error

In any case, as I also mentioned in your question on firebird-support, the error means that the security database hasn't been initialized yet, and you need to create a user using an embedded connection before you can establish a remote (TCP/IP) connection. This is also the difference with your FlameRobin connection and the connection you used by creating a database in ISQL.

The error means FlameRobin attempted to authenticate with Srp, but the security database wasn't initialized yet for Srp. You need to create at least one user using the Srp plugin to initialize the security database.
So, connect - with ISQL, in embedded mode - to a database (e.g. to employee) and execute
create user sysdba password '<a password>' using plugin srp;

That you were able to create a database with ISQL using CREATE DATABASE '/db/xeroxnew.fdb' USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey'; is because you don't specify a host name or a protocol in the database-path, so it defaults to embedded mode to create the database, which means it doesn't perform authentication.
To be clear, this problem is not specific to FlameRobin, it would occur with any tool or library using a remote protocol to connect to your Firebird server, instead of connecting in-process using Firebird Embedded.

This is a reworded version of my answer in this thread on firebird-support.
